# XSLT format-number() function issue with large number

Tags: java, xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(12345678911234567891,'0')"/>
```

gives 12345678911234570640 as a result instead of 12345678911234567891.

It works for number with max 15 digits.e.g

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(999999999999999,'0')"/>
```

gives exactly 999999999999999 as a result.

Why the number is changed? What would be the solution to display it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Java you could consider moving to Saxon 9 as an XSLT 2.0 processor and using the `xs:decimal` type support in XSLT/XPath 2.0:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:decimal(.), '0')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

with the input being

```
<data>12345678911234567891</data>
```

outputs `12345678911234567891`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it depends on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

XSLT 1.0 only has one numeric type (double precision floating point) and this is not capable of representing your long integer precisely.

In XSLT 2.0 your value is an integer, and all implementations are required to support integers of up to 18 digits. Your integer has 20 digits, so you may still see some variations between implementations.

Saxon handles integers of "unlimited" size (that is to say, you'll probably run out of memory before it complains that the integer has too many digits).

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet of saxons with 20 digits double value?

Comment: Code snippet to do what? The code in your question will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to floating point rounding. An IEEE754 floating point double is incapable of distinguishing those two numbers.

`12345678911234570640` is the one that *is* representable exactly in floating point, so that's the one you get back.

15 significant figures is the accuracy limit of a floating point double which is why it works in that case.